# how to check wheather application is up & running in the server?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to check whether application up & running or down , because of some error in the application. I can able to monitor server using process ID , but there is possible application down but server up & running.

I want to monitor the application URL , like `http://10.1.1.1:8080/test`. i can't ping the url , because its not an DNS server.

So how to monitor the application url whether is working good or some error occur. Please advise...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). You need to configure it with number of attempts to try, and I'd recommend a low-ish timeout value too, whatever you think an acceptable response is. It will return 0 if it could download the page and non-zero otherwise.

```
#!/bin/sh

if wget "$1" -O /dev/null --tries 1 --quiet --timeout 5; then echo "Up"; else echo "Down"; fi
```

Example

```
check-site.sh "http://10.1.1.1:8080/test"
```

Comment: If you took out the `function` keyword (which adds gratuitous incompatibility but has no other effect), your script would work with any POSIX sh interpreter, and thus could be `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`. If, by contrast, you _want_ to use bashisms, I'd suggest using `if (( $? == 0 ))` when doing math -- C-style syntax in math contexts being cleaner and easier to read [but see next comment re: a way to avoid the math entirely].

Comment: ...also, one could more simply write this as: `if wget ...; then echo "Up"; else echo "Down"; fi` and dispense with the need to test `$?`.

Comment: `==` isn't guaranteed by POSIX to work inside of `[ ]` (which uses only a single `=` as a string comparison operator) -- that's why I suggested it in `(( ))`.

Comment: Got it working with inline if command; syntax now anyway. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: No worries. BTW, I tried to do a whitespace cleanup to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling, but it looks like it got eaten by a concurrent edit. I'm not putting it back in case that was deliberate -- wouldn't want an edit war.